# angularjs $event get the same code for uppercase and lowercase for a key

Tags: angularjs, keyboard-events, uppercase, lowercase

i'm struggling to create hotkeys using angularjs $event. i need to simplify the codes for uppercase and lowercase. however i viewed from the console.log($event) they have different keyCode.

p is 112
P is 80

HTML:

```
<body ng-app="pointofsale" ng-controller="PointofSaleCtrl" ng-keypress="hotKeyEvent($event)">
```

Javascript:

```
$scope.hotKeyEvent = function(data){
    console.log(data);

    switch(data.keyCode){
        case 112: // p

            break;
        case 80:  // P

            break;

        default:
            console.log('No key associated')

    }
}
```

What am i missing here? i don't want to create two conditions for the same character but different case.

Appreciate any help, Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simplify your switch by grouping the case statements

like this:

```
switch(data.keyCode){

         case 112: // p
         case 80:  // P

            break;       

        default:
            console.log('No key associated')
    }
```

It's known as falling through - essentially, anything matched will continue to run until a `break` is hit.

Makes maintenance  quite a bit easier too.

Comment: thanks! this works. i'll do this for now. i wished i could just use it like this case 112 || 80: or a single code for both uppercase or lowercase :)

Comment: unfortunately, that syntax `case 112 || 80` isn't valid, so it's not possible with a `switch`; unless you used it in an `if`. If this helps, please accept the answer :)